# How to parse the tensorflow events file?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I would like to know how to extract the same performance results from the `events` file of the output of a model as does `Tensorboard` : specifically the Precision, Recall, and Loss numbers are most of interest. Here is a subset of them displayed on `Tensorboard` given the model checkpoint directory:

[image]

I'm not sure if there self-documenting information or other metadata available for these models. This one in particular is the `Faster RNN Inception`: but are these outputs tied to a particular model or are they generic in format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the approach in the *tensorboard* package:

```
  from tensorboard.backend.event_processing.event_accumulator import EventAccumulator
  event_acc = EventAccumulator(evtf)
  event_acc.Reload()
```

One of the entries is:

```
  scal_losses = event_acc.Scalars('Loss/total_loss')
```

From that list we can extract such attributes as `Step` [number]  and `Value` (of the *loss*):

```
 losses = sorted([[sevt.step, sevt.value] for sevt in scal_losses])
```