# Tensorboard printed summary Precision and Accuracy does not show the Step count

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

We want to correlate the StepCount with the trends of Precision and Accuracy. The Tensorboard GUI allows this: but we want to automate the results.  The printed results do not print the Step Count - at least not by default:

[image]

Is there a way to tease the Step Count from Tensorboard's printed results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps are actually available in the *TF Events* file but require coding to extract and correlate.  I show how to do that here:  [How to parse the tensorflow events file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57813373/how-to-parse-the-tensorflow-events-file)